# If both are available, does Android BiometricManager default to Face Recognition or Fingerprint?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, xamarin

I do not have a device to test this scenario with, but I have seen a lot of people complaining that when both Face Recognition and Fingerprint were available on their device, the app decided to use Fingerprint authentication instead.

I have not been able to find any article or documentation that talks about this preference, and I am not sure if those users were using BiometricPrompt vs BiometricManager.

Does anyone know if both are available, does Android BiometricManager/BiometricPrompt default to Face/Iris recognition or Fingerprint? Also is there a way to force one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar kind of requirement, And after my research, I came to know as of now (Android 10) it depends on OEM's implementation to provide either fingerprint or face recognition for app's authentication.

From Android R, there will be a way to get a prompt to choose authentication either fingerprint or facial.

Please have a look at the below issues been raised for a similar requirement.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641

Comment: _"From Android R, there will be a way to get a prompt to choose authentication either fingerprint or facial"_. Not really. They'll let the app choose between WEAK and STRONG biometrics (or both), but there's no way to specify fingerprint or face (e.g. a device could potentially have both fingerprint and face support, with both of them being classified as STRONG).

Comment: Thanks for your response. "..as of now (Android 10) it depends on OEM's implementation to provide either fingerprint or face recognition for app's authentication..", where did you read/find that that?

Comment: @Ferraro could you please answer my follow up question ^

Comment: @Saamer I am working in a product-based enterprise company, and I came to know above information from our own OEM vendor when we are trying to implement our own authentication system, therefore because of company's policy can't disclose some documentation, You can even refer below issue which highlights my statements https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142150327